# Can the starting point of an infinite series be a non-integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can one have for example $$\sum_{k=\pi}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

The idea being that one would successively plug in $\pi$, then $\pi+1$, then $\pi+2$ and so on.

If it is possible, there are surprising (for me) consquences. Take the function q(x), that is 1 if x rational and 0 otherwise. Then the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}q(k)$$ diverges, but

$$\sum_{k=\pi}^{\infty}q(k)$$ converges.

So is this possible?

Specifically, I am dealing with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|sin(k)|}{k}$ and I wanted to make the transformation $k = \pi/2(2z+1)$, but then the new series starts at $1/\pi-1/2$

Comment: Well, you could just write $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1{(\pi+k)^2}$.

Comment: Notation means whatever we define it to mean.  I have personally never seen it defined in such a way as to allow anything but an integer (*or infinity as a shorthand to refer to the related limit as said integer approaches infinity*) as either bound, but I don't see why such a generalization should be completely outlawed either.

Comment: Well I have a series in k, starting with k= 1 and I would like to make a transformation $k =\pi/2 (2z+1)$, which forces z to be irrational, so I wondered if that is ok.

Comment: Is there any sense to define a function in points which do not enter the summation?

Comment: lol, there isn't. I didn't realize. anyway it's too late here my brain must be malfunctioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may, but keep in mind that it is not useful. I have never seen a sum tht uses irrational numbers, and that's for a good reason. You won't be able to do anything useful.

In answer to your "weird" case, it is only an result of 1) the fact that sum notation goes stepwise in integers, and 2) the function you chose.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is correct in this context, but if some index set is not countable, the sum can't be performed over $\mathbb{N}$ or any other countable set. Thus, we want to have the notion of  summing over other sets of indices, such as the irrationals.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you have any ordered set of indices $\mathcal{A}$ and a collection of numbers $\{\rho_\alpha \}_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}}$, you can write 
$$
\sum_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}\rho_\alpha
$$

Comment: Not quite. If the index set isn't finite the sum may depend on the order in which the partial sums are computed.

Comment: Indeed. Rewriting "... an ordered set of indices $\mathcal{A}$..." would fix this?

Comment: Yes, that fix works.

Comment: Also, I never knew why did partitions of unity have to require local finiteness, or why are paracompact spaces so useful.I guess this is why, and it's for a pretty important reason!